# RPC failed; Curl 56 OpenSSL error when deploying app to heroku

Tags: heroku, git

I keep getting the following error when i try to push my application using heroku.

```
numerating objects: 62, done.
Counting objects: 100% (62/62), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (57/57), done.
Writing objects: 100% (62/62), 16.52 MiB | 25.21 MiB/s, done.
Total 62 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac, 
errno 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

What I've tried:

Increasing postBuffer size

git config --global http.postBuffer 52428800000

deleting/ reinitializing git init

somethings that may be relevant. -The app size is about 140MB.

I use express, multer, sessions
Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49720604/error-rpc-failed-curl-56-openssl-ssl-read-error140943fcssl-routinesssl3-re

Comment: suggestion did not work for me. I am still getting the same issue. Thank you though

Comment: @nick I am having the same issue did you manage to resolve it by any chance

Comment: @the_big_blackbox sorry for the late response. I solved the issue by deploying the app through herukos website itself instead of terminal I believe.